# Linear regression proof that SST = SSR + SSE

Tags: statistics, linear-regression

[image]

My teacher wanted us to try to attempt to prove this. So I noticed the summation on the left represents SST (total sum of squares) and on the right I noticed the second summation was the measure in variability of the y's in the linear regression term. However what is that first summation? Also how can I manipulate the right side to get the left side?

Comment: What is $\bar{Y}_i$?

Comment: I'm honestly very confused.. because that first summation poses very similar to Yi with ^ but my teacher wrote a bar instead. Do you think it was an error?

Comment: Yeah usually it is written $\sum_{i} (Y_i - \bar{Y})^2 = \sum_i (Y_i - \hat{Y}_i)^2 + \sum_i  (\hat{Y}_i - \bar{Y})^2$ i.e. SST = SSR + SSE. Check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination

Comment: yeah that's what I have noticed from online... this is to represent anova, correct?

Comment: http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~fwood/teaching/W4315_Fall2010/Lectures/lecture_6/lecture_6.pdf 
So I'm following the solution to the proof here. Do you know how they got the line after they factored the summation?

Comment: @Lil Does the answer help or not ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i-\overline y)^2=\sum_{i=1}^n((\hat y_i-\overline y)+(y_i - \hat y_i))^2$

$=\sum_{i=1}^n((\hat y_i-\overline y)^2+2(\hat y_i-\overline y)(y_i-\hat y_i)+(y_i-\hat y_i)^2)$

$\sum_{i=1}^n(\hat y_i-\overline y)^2+\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i-\hat y_i)^2+2\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i-\hat y_i)(\hat y_i-\overline y)$

$\sum_{i=1}^n(\hat y_i-\overline y)^2+\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i-\hat y_i)^2+2\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i-\hat y_i)(\hat\beta_0+\hat\beta_1x_{i1}+\hat\beta_2x_{i2}+...+\hat\beta_mx_{im}-\overline y)$

Now let $\hat u_i=y_i-\hat y_i$

$\sum_{i=1}^n(\hat y_i-\overline y)^2+\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i-\hat y_i)^2+2\sum_{i=1}^n\hat u_i(\hat\beta_0+\hat\beta_1x_{i1}+\hat\beta_2x_{i2}+...+\hat\beta_mx_{im}-\overline y)$

$\sum_{i=1}^n(\hat y_i-\overline y)^2+\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i-\hat y_i)^2+2(\hat\beta_0-\overline y)\cdot \sum_{i=1}^n \hat u_i+2\hat\beta_1 \sum_{i=1}^n \hat u_ix_{i1}+2\hat\beta_2 \sum_{i=1}^n \hat u_ix_{i2}+...+2\hat\beta_m \sum_{i=1}^n \hat u_ix_{im}$

It is $\sum_{i=1}^n \hat u_i=0$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n \hat u_ix_{ij}=0 \ \ \forall j=1,2,...,m$

Finally it becomes

$\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i-\overline y)^2=\sum_{i=1}^n(\hat y_i-\overline y)^2+\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i-\hat y_i)^2$

Comment: In the proof, before "Finally"; `Sigma1n Uihat=0` has a proof here:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/494181/why-the-sum-of-residuals-equals-0-when-we-do-a-sample-regression-by-ols I could not see why the latter holds: For all `j=1,...,.m` `Sigma1n UihatXij=0`

Comment: Now, I got it. In the same link, the partial derivative wrt to b gives the second fact above, i.e., For all `j=1,...,.m` `Sigma1n UihatXij=0`. It would be better the answer included the proofs of these 2 facts as well.

Comment: @ErdoganCEVHER It seems that it wasn´t required, otherwise the OP would have asked for it. With you hints an interested reader can have a look to it. Anyway your comments are helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an elementary proof that SST = SSR + SSE in the case of simple linear regression.

First recall the estimators for slope and intercept are
$$(1)\quad\hat\beta_1:=\frac{\sum(y_i-\bar y)(x_i-\bar x)}{\sum(x_i-\bar x)^2}\qquad(2)\quad\hat\beta_0:=\bar y - \hat\beta_1\bar x$$
respectively, and the $i$th predicted response is
$$\hat y_i:=\hat\beta_0+\hat\beta_1x_i\stackrel{(2)}=\bar y + \hat\beta_1(x_i-\bar x).\tag3$$
Now compute
$$\begin{aligned}
SST&:=\sum (y_i-\bar y)^2=\sum\left[(y_i-\hat y_i) + (\hat y_i-\bar y)\right]^2\\
&=\underbrace{\sum(y_i-\hat y_i)^2}_{SSE} +2\sum(y_i-\hat y_i)(\hat y_i-\bar y)+\underbrace{\sum(\hat y_i-\bar y)^2}_{SSR}.
\end{aligned}$$
The middle term must equal zero. Indeed, substitute (3) twice and do some algebra:
$$\begin{aligned}
\sum(y_i-\hat y_i)(\hat y_i-\bar y)&
\stackrel{(3)}=\sum\left(y_i-[\bar y+\hat\beta_1(x_i-\bar x)]\right)\cdot\hat\beta_1(x_i-\bar x)\\
&=\sum\left([y_i-\bar y]-\hat\beta_1(x_i-\bar x)\right)\cdot\hat\beta_1(x_i-\bar x)\\
&=\hat\beta_1\sum(y_i-\bar y)(x_i-\bar x) -\hat\beta_1^2\sum(x_i-\bar x)^2
\end{aligned}
$$ But this last quantity is zero because $\sum(y_i-\bar y)(x_i-\bar x)=\hat\beta_1\sum(x_i-\bar x)^2$ by (1).