# Why the sum of residuals in regression model equals 0 when there is a constant term(of ones)?

Tags: statistics, regression

Suppose we have model $Y = X\beta$ and first collumn of $X$ consists of $1$.
Why the sum of residuals in the this regression model equals $0$? And why in generall it doesn't, when there is no constant term?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why the sum of residuals equals 0 when we do a sample regression by OLS?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/494181/why-the-sum-of-residuals-equals-0-when-we-do-a-sample-regression-by-ols)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the linear model of a form $Y=\beta_0 + \sum_{j=1}^p\beta_jx_j + \epsilon $, so to find the OLS estimator you construct 
$$
\min_{\beta \in \mathcal B}\sum_{i=1}^n(Y_i-\beta_0 + \sum_{j=1}^p\beta_jx_j)^2,
$$
then when you take the derivative w.r.t the intercept term $\beta_0$, you get the following expression
$$
-2\sum_{i=1}^n(Y_i-\hat{\beta_0} + \sum_{j=1}^p\hat{\beta}_jx_j) = 2\sum_{i=1}^ne_i=0.
$$
Or, using matrix notations, you get the normal equations that your $\beta$ solves, i.e., 
$$
X'X\hat{\beta}-X'y=0,
$$
namely,
$$
X'(X\hat\beta - y) = X'e=0,
$$
where the first row is $1^Te =\sum_{i=1}^ne_i $.