# Why is $E(u)=0$ when an intercept is included in OLS Estimation?

Tags: statistics, expectation, regression, least-squares

I am reading Wooldridge's graduate econometrics text. There he states that when estimating the equation $y=\mathbf{x\beta}+u$ by OLS, if an intercept (constant term) is included in your $\mathbf{x}$ vector, so that $\mathbf{x}=(1,x_1,...,x_k)$, where $y$ and the other $x_1,...,x_k$ are random variables, then we have automatically that $E(u)=0$. I  am trying to see why.

Later on, when the textbook introduces OLS, one of the assumptions is that $E(\mathbf{x}^{\top}u)=\mathbf{0}$. Now note that if $\mathbf{x}$ contains an intercept, then this statement implies that $E(u)=0$. However I believe this assumption is not needed to know that when an intercept is included, then $E(u)=0$, rather we have $E(u)=0$ "for free" as the textbook says.

I found a similar question (with name not representative of its question/answer) located here:
[Why the expected value of the error when doing regression by OLS is 0?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/493169/why-the-sum-of-residuals-when-doing-a-sample-regression-by-ols-is-0)
which says the constant effectively "absorbs" $E(u)$ to make $E(u)=0$. How does this work, in theory?

My questions:

1. How do we know that an intercept "absorbs" $E(u)$ exactly -- no more, no less?
2. Does this rely on the assumption $E(\mathbf{x}^{\top}u)=\mathbf{0}$?

Thanks!

---

**Edit** My econometrics instructor notes that if we include an intercept, so that \begin{equation}y=\beta_0+\mathbf{x\beta}+u,\end{equation}
where $E(u)=\alpha\ne0$, then we can always rewrite the first equation as
\begin{align*}
y&=(\alpha+\beta_0)+\mathbf{x\beta}+(u-\alpha) \\
&=(\alpha+\beta_0)+\mathbf{x\beta}+\tilde{u},
\end{align*}
where $\tilde{u}=u-\alpha$ and $E(\tilde{u})=0$.

However this still doesn't explain how we get $E(u)$, so that we can "include" it in our intercept. (We can only *estimate* $E(u)$, but how do we do that?)

I know that if $x_0=1$ and all the other $x_1,...,x_k$ equal $0$ then what really happens is $\hat{\beta}=(x^{\top}x)^{-1}x^{\top}y=y$... Am I getting there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't know the expected value of the error term -and we do not argue that it equals the estimated value of the constant term, since the constant term may also estimate a "shift factor" anticipated by theory.

Assume that no such shift factor is postulated, then the theory would tell you to specify

$$y=\mathbf{x'\beta}+u$$

with no constant term. Hmmm, are you *sure* that the error term has a zero mean? Isn't it possible that the model you are implementing has somehow "got it wrong", and apart from the regressors included in $\mathbf x$, there are also other variables that do influence $y$ in the real world? If this is the case then you should expect $E(u) \neq 0$. Then write $u \equiv u-E(u) + E(u)$ and so you are looking at

$$y=\mathbf{x'\beta} + u-E(u) + E(u) \Rightarrow y=E(u) + \mathbf{x'\beta} + (u-E(u)) $$

$E(u)$ is unknown of course -but *it is a constant*. So setting $E(u) \equiv \beta_0$, you obtain

$$y=\beta_0 + \mathbf{x'\beta} + (u-E(u)) $$

But you can *estimate* $\beta_0$ through OLS, while the error term that you "ignore" is here $(u-E(u))$ and so has expected value zero.

The "intercept" is not the known regressor comprised of the series of ones. The intercept is the *unknown coefficient* attached to this regressor. But since this regressor is a series of ones, we do not write it explicitly in the specification, which should be

$$y_i = 1\cdot \beta_0 + \mathbf x_i' \beta + u_i$$
and in vector matrix notation

$$\mathbf y = \mathbf 1 \beta_0 + \mathbf X\beta + \mathbf u$$

where $\mathbf 1 = (1,1,1,...,1)'$

Comment: Thank you for your answer! What do you mean by "So setting $E(u)=\beta_0$? This is precisely what I don't get -- How do we make sure $\beta_0=E(u)$? For example, what if instead of adding and subtracting $E(u)$, we instead added and subtracted something else, like the number $7$?

Comment: I think I understand. Please tell me if this is correct. The ONLY WAY we can estimate the $\beta_0,...,\beta_k$ is if we have $E(u)=0$ (we need this assumption). Thus, this requirement leads to an important fact: If $E(u)\ne 0$, then when we run OLS and estimate $\beta_0$, we are actually estimating $E(u)$ instead of estimating $0$? (Otherwise, if $E(u)=0$ is actually true, then estimating $\beta_0$ would have given us what we expect: $\beta_0=0$, correct?)

Comment: "If $E(u)≠0$, then when we run OLS and estimate $β_0$, we are actually estimating $E(u)$ instead of estimating $0$?" Yes. That's the essence of it.