# mean response and mean response change in linear regression

Tags: statistics, expectation, regression

I have [read](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/482910/mean-response-in-linear-regression) and I think understood the fact that in linear regression, the predicted response is the mean value (expected value) of y given (conditioned on) a particular regressor value $x_d$.

However there is an additional claim, and I would like to understand how these two are related: That the regression coefficients $\beta$ represent a mean **change** in the response variable given a unit change of the particular regressor. So, are these statements related?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In linear regression, we assume that $\mathbb{E}[y \mid \mathbf{x}]$, where $\mathbf{x}$ is a given, known vector of predictors $$\mathbf{x}^{T} = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & x_1 & x_2 &\cdots &x_p
\end{bmatrix}$$is given by the form
$$\mathbb{E}[y \mid \mathbf{x}] = \mathbf{x}^{T}\boldsymbol\beta=\beta_0+\beta_1x_1+\beta_2x_2+\cdots\beta_px_p\text{.}$$
For any $i = 1, \dots, p$, notice that 
$$\dfrac{\partial \mathbb{E}[y \mid \mathbf{x}]}{\partial x_i} = \beta_i\text{.}$$
Recall the intuition of partial derivatives: holding all other variables constant, it is the "slope" of the given function. Since the slope is $\beta_i$, what this indicates is that for each unit increase in $x_i$, the conditional expected value (or mean) would change by $\beta_i$.

(Of course, this assumes that this model for $\mathbb{E}[y \mid \mathbf{x}]$ is actually correct.)

Comment: ..many thanks<5

Comment: I have a quick follow up question actually, thinking more about it: Does this also imply that the residuum is the *mean* deviation between predicted and actual response?

Comment: @Pegah No, the residual is the difference $$y - \hat{y} = y - \hat{\mathbb{E}}[y \mid \mathbf{x}]$$
i.e., the difference between the actual response and the estimated (note the $\hat{\mathbb{E}}$) average response.